# Coded UI - Asserting StartsWith( ) not working as expected (VS 2015)

Tags: visual-studio, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

Im trying to build a test case where i retrieve a list of data objects and populate it in a datagrid.

I want to verify (assert) that the 1st row has a field/column that StartsWith  "ABC".

I can see that the generated code produces an element that basically has the field's exact display value (in this case it is "ABCDEFG").

Of course, when i run this test, it validates just fine because the generated element ("ABCDEFG") definitely startswith "ABC".

**The problem** is that the datagrid could be populated with dynamic data, so the field display could be something like "ABC-FOO" or even "XYZ" for instance.

**In short** the automated code that is generated seems to not behaving as i expect.

**I am expecting** to do a StartsWith assertion against the real-time field display, not a generated (hard-coded) string which i used to build the test with.

Am i doing something wrong here?
Am i missing something critical?
Or should i be abandoning Coded UI altogether?

Here is the generated element:

```
public HtmlLabel generatedLabel
{
    get
    {
        if ((this.mUIgeneratedLabelLabel == null))
        {
            this.mUIgeneratedLabelLabel = new HtmlLabel(this);
            #region Search Criteria
            this.mUIgeneratedLabelLabel.SearchProperties[HtmlLabel.PropertyNames.Id] = "Control_42";
            this.mUIgeneratedLabelLabel.SearchProperties[HtmlLabel.PropertyNames.Name] = null;
            this.mUIgeneratedLabelLabel.SearchProperties[HtmlLabel.PropertyNames.LabelFor] = null;
            this.mUIgeneratedLabelLabel.SearchProperties[HtmlLabel.PropertyNames.InnerText] = "ABCDEF-FOO";
            this.mUIgeneratedLabelLabel.FilterProperties[HtmlLabel.PropertyNames.Class] = "field-control";
            this.mUIgeneratedLabelLabel.FilterProperties[HtmlLabel.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition] = "class=\"field-control\" id=\"ControlB";
            this.mUIgeneratedLabelLabel.FilterProperties[HtmlLabel.PropertyNames.TagInstance] = "24";
            this.mUIgeneratedLabelLabel.WindowTitles.Add("MyTest");
            #endregion
        }
        return this.mUgeneratedLabelLabel;
    }
}
```

**---- Updated ----**

**To explain what my confusion is:** I've setup my StartsWith() assertion on some text ("ABCD") that has been retrieved dynamically. I created the asserttion to check if the text StartsWith "ABC". Now, when i look at the generated assertion code, i see that the assertion will always pass because the code is comparing the text's string literal ("ABCD") with the assertion check string literal ("ABC"). What I am looking for is to do the assertion check with whatever dynamic text is retrieved during the test run-time. Hope this makes it clear where im getting stuck.

Comment: I do not understand the question. Are you asking why the code you show contains the `... InnerText] = "ABCDEF-FOO";` line and what to do about it? If yes then why not delete that entry from the search properties. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/19703241/546871

Comment: Appended a detailed description to hopefully clarify where my confusion and issue is.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the assertion code.

Comment: Is your problem that you need to find the variable for comparison at run time, or that the comparison is not working right?

Comment: The problem is that the generated code is essentially hard-coding the strings to be compared (not one of the strings is dynamic). If i look at the generated code i can literally see the hard-coded strings ("ABC" vs "ABCD"). What i need is to be able to check a string "ABC" against a string value that is determined at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out where the problem is, you could first try doing 
`if (control.Text.Contains("ABC"))`, then try `if(control.Text.StartsWith("ABS"))`, and see where the problem emerges.