# Get value from radio button in codedUI

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automation, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to get a changing value from a radio button in a webpage for my codedUI test.
The problem is that each time this radio button `value` changes and my test has a fixed value for the radio button when I recorded the test using test builder.
Here is the html code for the radio button

```
<input aria-label="Check Domain Factvlog 2:53:47 PM" type="radio" name="id[]" value="10">
```

I tried to use the search configuration and I set it to `Always search` for the property `UIIDRadioButton`

I also Added this code trying to get the value from the htmlRadioButton element in the page, which I am not sure its correct or do the trick (I am not a coder).

```
HtmlRadioButton radioButton = new HtmlRadioButton();

radioButton.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlRadioButton.PropertyNames.Value, "value");
                radioButton.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlRadioButton.PropertyNames.Name, "id[]");
                radioButton.SearchProperties.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);


        HtmlRadioButton uIIDRadioButton = this.UIDashboardCommonLookCWindow.UICreateNewTaskCommonLDocument.UIIDRadioButton;
```

I always get this error when I run the test
Message: 
System.ArgumentException: The PropertyExpressionCollection.Add method can take only in name-value pairs.
Parameter name: nameValuePairs

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you just delete the `value` equals `10` part of the recorded search criteria? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19703241/546871 for more info.

Comment: @AdrianHHH thank you, but the post you referred to suggest to add the values before you run the code, which is not what I need.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. You have recorded a test and generated code. You say it has a test on `value` equals `10` that you do not want. The first paragraph of the answer I referenced shows how to edit the recorded test to remove part of it. That should leave the other parts of the recording (and allow you to add other clauses if you wanted). Please [edit] the question to explain what you really want.

Comment: @AdrianHHH , What I need here is to read the value="" while I am running the test, is there a way to read the html value in test run time and replace the "10" with the new value in search properties?

Comment: The normal way of handling fields that change value is to remove them from the search properties and to search using other, constant, fields. Is your question an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it the wrong way.

> " System.ArgumentException: The PropertyExpressionCollection.Add
>   method can take only in name-value pairs. Parameter name:
>   nameValuePairs "

This means that you have to assign a value to your searchconfiguration line.

Try this

```
radioButton.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);
```